# Azure TableEntity, overriding Write & ReadEntity methods

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table some enumerations like this

```
pk   rk   en     fr     de   ...

foo  1  'E-f1' 'F-f1' 'D-f1' ...
foo  2  'E-f2' 'F-f2' 'D-f2' ...

bar  1  'E-b1' 'F-b1' 'D-b1' ...
bar  2  'E-b2' 'F-b2' 'D-b2' ...
bar  3  'E-b3' 'F-b3' 'D-b3' ...
```

`en`, `fr`, `de` etc... are the language codes, and respectively the column names in the table.

When the user select a language I need to select dropdowns for "foo" and "bar"
I need to display dropdowns.

I created a `DescriptionEntity`, that has a `Description` that should keep the 'en' or 'fr' or 'de' text value, depending on the current user interface language.

Does the following code replace the `Description` property with the current language value in the Azure Table and read it respectively, or I misunderstand something (because there is not very clear for the in the documentation)...?

```
public class DescriptionEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private string lang;

    public DescriptionEntity(string lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext) {
        base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
        if (properties.ContainsKey(this.lang)) {
            this.Description = properties[this.lang].StringValue;
        }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var x = base.WriteEntity(operationContext);
        var descriptionValue = this.Description;
        if (x.ContainsKey(lang)) {
            x[lang].StringValue = this.Description;
        }
        else {
            x.Add(lang, new EntityProperty(this.Description));
        }
        x.Remove("Description");
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I created a DescriptionEntity, that has a Description that should keep the 'en' or 'fr' or 'de' text value, depending on the current user interface language.
>
> Does the following code replace the Description property with the current language value in the Azure Table and read it respectively, or I misunderstand something (because there is not very clear for the in the documentation)...?

Based on my test with the following sample, your code should replace the `Description` property with the language value based on the current user interface language.

**Entities in my Azure table:**

[image]

**DescriptionEntity class:**

```
public class DescriptionEntity : TableEntity
{
    public DescriptionEntity(string pk, string rk)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = pk;
        this.RowKey = rk;
    }
    public DescriptionEntity() { }

public string Description { get; set; }

    string lang = "en";

    public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
        if (properties.ContainsKey(lang))
        {
            this.Description = properties[lang].StringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Query entities:**

```
TableQuery<DescriptionEntity> query = new TableQuery<DescriptionEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "foo"));

foreach (DescriptionEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    string languages = entity.Description;
}
```

[image]